# JQuery Ajax Requests behaving unexpectedly

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, tomcat

I am using Jquerys Ajax method to talk to my web service. The code seems OK, but I just monitored HTTP traffic using HTTPFox firefox plugin and I noticed unexpected results. To begin with, I am setting the `ContentType` as `application/json` and my web service is also producing `JSON` data but HTTPFox indicates Content Type for my HTTP requests as `application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)`.

The Request Method is `GET` as set in my Ajax request, but HTTPFox indicates my Request method as `OPTIONS`. And while the Request succeeds and data is returned,  the `onSuccess` method of my Ajax request is not called. Instead, the `onError` method is called. HTTP Fox is able to capture the data from my web service as response. See the image for HTTP Fox.

Finally, all other request from other processes in my browser seem OK but my HTTP requests are flagged 'RED' by HTTP Fox. The request from other pages and processes seem OK.( GREEN or WHITE).

I have attached screenshot of HTTPFox highlighted on one of my Request. The flagged ones are also from my application.

Image:
[image]

I have also pasted the Ajax code I am using to make the HTTP Requests.

```
window.onload = function() {

var seq_no = getParameterByName("seq_no");
var mileage = getParameterByName("mileage");

document.getElementById("seq_no").value = seq_no;
document.getElementById("mileage").value = mileage;
var param = 'vehReg='+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('vehReg').value);
//  alert(param);
loadVehicleInfo(param);
};

 function loadVehicleInfo(params) {
 $("#message").html('<p><font color="green">Loading...</font></p>');
 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://localhost:8080/stockcloud/rest/vehicles/info",
     data: params,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: 
             function(data,status) {
         $("#message").empty();
         $("#message").html('<p>'+getAsUriParameters(data)+'</p>');

             },
                     error : 
                     function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                         $("#message").html("<p> <font color='red'>The following error occurred: " +textStatus+ ': '+errorThrown+ "</font>");

                     }

                });
            };

    function getAsUriParameters (data) {
        return Object.keys(data).map(function (k) {
            if (_.isArray(data[k])) {
                var keyE = encodeURIComponent(k + '[]');
                return data[k].map(function (subData) {
                    return keyE + '=' + encodeURIComponent(subData);
                }).join('&');
            } else {
                return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k]);
            }
        }).join('&');
        };

        function getParameterByName(name) {
           name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
          var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
               results = regex.exec(location.search);
             return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Server side Code for the request:

```
@Path("/vehicles")
```

public class VehiclesService {

```
@GET
@Path("info")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getVehicleInfo(@DefaultValue("__DEFAULT__") @QueryParam("vehReg") String vehReg) {
       // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
    ServerResponse resp = new ServerResponse();

    if("__DEFAULT__".equals(vehReg)) {
        resp.setError("Vehicle registration must be supplied as a query parameter:  ?vehReg=<THE REG NO>");
        resp.setResult(false);
        Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(resp).build();
    }

    try {
        // actual code to return the car info and return XML string with the info.

        connection.disconnect();
        String xml = URLDecoder.decode(s.toString(),"UTF-8");
        xml  = xml.replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&gt;", ">").replace("<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes' ?>", "");
        System.out.println(xml);

        resp.setVehicle(new VehicleParse().parse(xml));
        resp.setResult(true);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        resp.setResult(false);
        resp.setError(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(resp).build();
    }

    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(resp).build();
    }
}
```

Is there something I am not doing right?

Thanks.

Comment: it look like that the `param` var isn't a `JSON` type but a `string`.. am i right? yet you try to send it to the server as a JSON

Comment: yea, thanks. param is a string. is that the wrong, the way am sending it?

Comment: i don't know what the server side request for this app is, so i can't help you with that..

Comment: Hi Michael, I just edited the question including the server code. The server is a java web service deployed in tomcat 7. Kindly have a look, I appreciate the help.

Comment: i'm not familiar with java web service and tomcat, but try to cut out of the code the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` and `dataType: "json"` and see what happens

Comment: OK Micheal. Thanks. I will try. I appreciate you big time, for trying to help.

Comment: sorry... try to tag also tomcat and java.. good luck!

Comment: Hi Micheal, how would I do the tagging?

Comment: hit the `edit` below your post, than scroll dow until you see the section **Tags** add there after your current tags the relevant tags for you, use space between tags